# pg_dump with proper table dependency analysis?

Tags: postgresql, restore, pg-dump, dump

Is it possible to dump then recreate with proper table analysis,
so for example if table A depends on table B, then table B will be dumped first, then the table A

something like

```
CREATE TABLE B(...);

COPY ... TO B;

CREATE TABLE A(...);

COPY ... TO A;

ALTER TABLE A ADD FOREIGN KEY ... REFERENCES B(...);
CREATE INDEX ON A ....;
```

I'm trying to dump from one database to another database directly:

```
pg_dump -U user1 -h db1.rds.amazonaws.com db1 | 
pv | 
psql -U user2 -h localhost -p 15432 db2
```

Comment: pg_dump creates all constraints and indexes at the end, so the order of the inserts isn't really relevant.

Comment: oh cool, will try to do this hard cutover with this way (since bucardo has an error)